# How to convert Esri Compact Cache to other format? (mbtiles, et.c.)

Tags: convert

I need to convert Esri Compact Cache-files to a "better" (a more open & common) format. Ideally I would like to convert to mbtiles or just 'tiles on disk'.

What software can perform this conversion, and how is it done?

The Compact Cache-files I'm working with can be downloaded from this site (see "Offline products"):
https://www.basemap.at/index_en.html#sec-zugang